# How do i import a Database Dump .sql file via Console

Tags: mysql

I'm Using WAMP Stack on Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit

I have a Database Dump (test-mysql.sql) file, which, for simplicity, i've located at

> C:/test-mysql.sql

Using MYSQL CONSOLE (not Windows cmd.exe)

I'm trying to simply import this file into MySQL, assuming this file will be imported as it's own database, have not yet created a database for it.If a database name needs to be specified, i would like it to be tested.

I've tried the following combinations of code :

```
-u Martin.Kuliza -p test < test.mysql.sql;

mysql -u Martin.Kuliza -p test < test-mysql.sql;

mysql -p -u Martin.Kuliza test < test-mysql.sql;

mysql -p -uMartin.Kuliza test < test-mysql.sql;
```

I Keep Getting **Error 1064 (42000)**

My Understanding is that the syntax is as follows,

> after the prompt mysql>

I'm supposed to use the following syntax,

```
mysql -p -u{Username} {Database Name} < {Dump File Name.extension}
```

Why is this not working..

thanks ahead of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martin, you need to provide absolute path in window something like this

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\mysql.exe -u root -p db_name < C:/test-mysql.sql
```

Comment: hey mate, it looks to me like your providing the answer for me (Assuming i was i'm using a windows CLI Shell), and i thankyou for your answer and understand how to do it from cmd.exe,  and i understand how to do it from PHP MyAdmin interface,   I've already Justified the Absolute Path in windows and created a desktop icon, so i don't have to login via windows CLI Shell and type mysql, then enter the password,  i just click on my icon and it automatically loads the MYSQL Console, i then enter the password and i'm off,  i need to know how to do this from MYSQL CONSOLE not cmd Shell

Comment: sorry Ram, i see what you were trying to say, You wanted me to go to cmd.exe and justify the "start in" path,  WELL. Logically then in CONSOLE iwould just need to type in < C:/test-msql.sql   i'll try that

Comment: Tried that   {<C:/test-mysql.sql;}  does not work, same error message

Comment: can you show me your mysql table because I feel your table may have special character in table name or extra comma in table fields

Comment: How would i show it to you? FYI i'm a computer engineer, but i'm new to mysql , sorry , Please be patient with me,

Comment: do you mean, you want me to go into the table and then copy and paste the contents to you?

Comment: DOES THIS HELP.  if i got to PHP MyAdmin and import the db, the output is as follows...  see the main comment edited with the output

Comment: if it's single table than show me otherwise you can go through with that. I don't want your table structure.

Comment: i can't show you , because this field says it exceeds the max character length, can't post it in the main post either.  it's not a table,  it's actually a database dump file called   test-mysql.sql  i just want to know how to import the database dump into mysql using console to do that

Comment: here is a copy and paste of the exact file name without the .sql extension    test-mysql

Comment: Can anyone Else help me on this??